# Python - is there a "don't care" symbol for tuple assignments?

Tags: python, syntax

Given a string "VAR=value" I want to split it (only) at the **first** '=' sign (< value > may contain more '=' signs), something like this:

```
var, sep, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')
```

Is there a way to NOT declare a variable 'sep'? Like this (just made up the syntax):

```
var, -, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')
```

Just for completeness, I'm targetting Python v 2.6

Comment: Probably worth pointing out here in the comments that in this case, you would actually use `split` instead of `partition`.  That is, `var, value = 'VAR=value'.split('=')`.  Good, succinct example though.

Comment: @Cody `split` only works in this case with a maxsplit argument. `partition` seems to be preferred. See comments below http://stackoverflow.com/a/2745082/11545 for details from people more knowledgeable than me

Comment: The `maxsplit` argument specifies **how many splits** are made, so `maxsplit=1` would be used here, i.e., at most one split into at most two pieces. This can be confusing because some other scripting languages (Perl, PowerShell, etc) use a similar parameter to specify instead how many substrings are created, so the argument in those cases would then be 2 instead of 1. This must be a source of subtle bugs when porting scripts.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`_` is indeed a very popular choice for "a name which doesn't matter" -- it's a legal name, visually unobtrusive, etc.  However sometimes these very qualities can hinder you.  For example, the GNU [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html) module for I18N and L10N, which is part of Python's standard library, idiomatically uses `_` very differently, with idioms such as...:

```
_ = gettext.gettext
# ...
print _('This is a translatable string.')
```

to mark and translate all the literal-string messages in the code (also exploiting the relative visual unobtrusiveness of `_('...')`.  Obviously any code using this module and idiom shouldn't also be using `_` to mean something completely different ("a don't care name").

So a second useful alternative can be to devote the name `unused` to indicate such "don't care" situations in a visually more explicit way.  Google's [python style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html) recommends using either `_` or a *prefix* of `unused_` -- the latter can be a bit verbose but tends to be very clear, e.g.:

```
name, unused_surname, salutation = person_data
print "Hello, %s %s!" % (salutation, name)
```

makes crystal-clear that `person_data` is a three-item sequence (probably a tuple) and the item you're skipping (and not using at all) is the surname (because you want to print a friendly message like "Hello, Mr Alex!" or "Hello, Miss Piggy!" ;-).  (`pylint` and similar tools can warn you if you have unused variables named otherwise than `_` or `unused_...`, and of course also warn you if you ever *do* use a variable named `unused_something`!-).

Comment: Nice point on gettext, I think I might done that sometime without realising.

Answer (score 16):

Almost there:

```
var, _, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')
```

`_` is conventionally considered a don't-care variable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the convention for multiple don't-cares? Just keep adding `_` characters? Or reuse the same `_` name?

Comment: @Hank: you can just re-use single underscore, also if those variables come in a sequence you could just pack them back into a tuple, like this: `a, *_, e = range(5)`. In py2k `*_` can only be last parameter

Comment: I think you're mistaken: Python 2.x doesn't allow this assignment syntax at all.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything official in the language for that; you can just use any throw-away variable.  As far as standards go, I've seen underscores used occasionally in Python and other languages.  The only issue there is that underscore is used as an alias for `gettext` when localizing.  But if you aren't doing localization, or aren't using the global-binding for it, then underscore should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Really strange question, because you can do just:

```
var, _, value = s.partition(sep)
```

and don't care about `_` variable, but `_` is just a name as `sep`, as `var` or `value`. By the way use `str.split`

```
>>> var, value = "VAR=value".split('=')
>>> var, value
('VAR', 'value')
>>>
```

Comment: `str.split` is much slower and `str.partition` is designed for exactly this situation.

Comment: @Silent Guys, `str.partition` splits only at the **first** occurence of 'sep', so if I have var,_,value = "AAA=bbb=ccc", value will be assigned 'bbb=ccc' which is what I want; `str.split` splits at **each** occurence of 'sep'; there are more differences, see the docs. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html

Comment: @Cristi Diaconescu: `split` has a `maxsplit` parameter.

Comment: One major issue with `split()` is the number of results varies while `partition()` always gives 3 results.  So, `(a,b) = "something".split(',')` throws an error while `(a, sep, b) = "something".partition(',')` does not.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `'VAR=value'.split('=')` instead? That disregards the delimiter.

**EDIT** (to accommodate Cristi's example in the comment):

From [Diving into Python](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/joining_lists.html):

> Tip: *anystring*.split(*delimiter*, 1) is a
>   useful technique when you want to
>   search a string for a substring and
>   then work with everything before the
>   substring (which ends up in the first
>   element of the returned list) and
>   everything after it (which ends up in
>   the second element).

Comment: because <value> may contain more '=' characters, and I only want to split at the first one.

Comment: Try `'VAR=value=full=of=equal=signs'.split('=',1)`.

Answer (score 2):

- Python doesn't have syntax to avoid assignment in unpacking and such.
- As others have mentioned, there is a convention of using `_` for variables you don't care about. This is fairly broadly used and understood, but personally I think it is underused. If you say `var, _, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')`, you have to know what's going on to know what the `_` was and why you didn't care about it when you read the code. If you say `var, sep, value` you document at the same time. This isn't very important for `str.partition`, but I've seen `_, _, name, _, city, _ = some_weird_function()` before and found it less useful than if everything was unpacked to useful names.
- You could technically use `str.split` here if you wanted to. `var, value = "foo=bar=baz".split("=", 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The _ is commonly used as a name for you **dont care** * For example, in a tuple containing the name, surname and nickname in a moment in which we are interested only in name and surname, could use _ to indicate that the name is not important at this point:

```
data = ('John', 'Mate', 'Little John')
name, surname, _ = data
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, underscore (`_`) is the standard. But if underscore is being used for translations, I think double underscore is the best alternative.

`var, __, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')`

Better than these:

`var, unused, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')`

`var, unused_del, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')`

`var, _del, value = "VAR=value".partition('=')`

Answer (score -1):

For numpy [`ndarrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), one can use indexing to choose particular elements:

```
arr_0, arr_2 = arr[[0, 2]]
```

Comment: This does not work if `my_list` is actually a list, only for Numpy arrays.