# Unneeded parts when unwrapping tuple/list

Tags: python, variable-assignment, pylint

Python is all about writing beautiful code. So, I was running `pylint` to check the "beautifulness" of my code, when I bump into something:

> Unused variable 'myvar1'

From this part of my code:

```
for myvar1, myvar2 in mylist:
    # Do stuff just using myvar2
```

`mylist` is a list of tuples, so I'm unwrapping the tuples into two variables (`myvar1` and `myvar2`). I'm defining those two variables just to unwrap the second one, because I don't need the other.

**So, here's my question:** Is there a way to tell the interpreter to unwrap the tuple, but not assing the first part (for example). In some other languages you can do something like:

```
for _, myvar in mylist:
    # Do stuff with myvar
```

or

```
for *, myvar in mylist:
    # Do stuff with myvar
```

That means: *I don't care about the first part of the tuple, I just need the second one.*

**NOTE:** I know that this could be an option for what I'm asking:

```
for mytuple in mylist:
    # Do stuff with mytuple[1]
```

But that's by far less readable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to @RaymondHettinger's answer: Pylint also does not complain about unused variables if their names start with a single underscore. This means that you can use:

```
for _myvar1, myvar2 in mylist:
```

getting the best of both worlds:

- no Pylint warning,
- and information about the record structure

This works for function / method prototypes too and avoids warnings about unused parameters, which you can often get when deriving from a base class in an OO framework.

Comment: so it mean that with `_` there is no Pylint warning either?

Comment: It seems that Pylint does not complain about unused variable if its name **starts** with `unused_` (literally). E.g. `for unused_myvar1, myvar2 in mylist:`. Prefix `unused_` is described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745537/3440745) for the related question.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try either of these?

```
for _, myvar in mylist:
    #Do stuff
```

works fine in Python and is relatively idiomatic.

Comment: yes, it does work. But its really assigning the first value of the tuple to the variable `_`, that's not the idea of my question

Comment: Well, you've listed your options, I would say that this is the most "beautiful". As you stated, the other options are more verbose and less easy to understand. Pylint is a good tool, but it is not the end all be all for code beauty (whatever that means).

Comment: For me this is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

I write `for _, myvar2 in mylist` when I want to emphasize that only *myvar2* is used.

And I write `for myvar1, myvar2 in mylist` when I want to remind the reader (usually me) what the record structure is.

The `_` name is just a naming convention for a throw-away value.  The CPython interpreter makes the variable assignment for it just like it would with any other variable name (fortunately, *STORE_FAST* is a very cheap operation).  In contrast, the [PyPy interpreter](http://pypy.org/) will identify the unused variable assignment as dead code, so you get the optimization for free regardless of how you write it.

If you're curious about how CPython interprets your code, the [dis module](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#module-dis) can provide useful insights:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f(lot):
        for _, var2 in lot:
            print var2


>>> dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              25 (to 28)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (lot)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                17 (to 27)
             10 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             13 STORE_FAST               1 (_)
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (var2)

  3          19 LOAD_FAST                2 (var2)
             22 PRINT_ITEM          
             23 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             24 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   27 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 RETURN_VALUE
```

As the other posters have mentioned, the warnings from *pylint* can sometimes be inane.  If you prefer a short variable name in your code, then just ignore the pylint complaint.  As Francis Avila pointed out, pylint should't complain about `_` in this context.

Comment: pylint also won't complain about unused arguments with names starting with a single underscore. This means that you can user "for _myvar1, myvar2 in mylist", getting the best of both worlds: no pylint warning, and information about the record structure.

Comment: I would add this comment as an answer @gurney-alex, because I think it's the best one.

Comment: @gurneyalex that's a very good observation, I'll look into that.

Comment: @FrancisAvila, I just did that.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could do this:

```
for myvar in (t[1] for t in mylist):
    pass
```

But frankly I think you should just ignore the pylint warning in this case--it's beautiful enough and won't cause any confusion (which is why you want to beauty in the first place).

Comment: I guess you're right. I asked this not because I wanted to avoid the `pylint` warning, but just out of curiosity

Answer (score 2):

I would say Python is all about writing *readable* code - any "beauty" is merely a side-effect.

The first item of the tuple could be eliminated like this:

```
for myvar2 in zip(*mylist)[1]:
    # Do stuff with myvar2
```

But I'm not sure I'd really recommend it. Personally I would just use:

```
for myvar1, myvar2 in mylist:
    # Do stuff with myvar2
```

... and ignore pylint.

Answer (score -1):

```
tu = [(12,'sea'),(478,'badada'),(789,'zut')]

for x,x in tu:
    print x
```

result

```
sea
badada
zut
```

### !

Comment: finally a reasonable answer, not the best thing to do, but at least answers my question.

Comment: This seems a lot less beautiful and clear than using different variable names, and only works if you want to ignore items on the left side. Would you automatically know which item is bound to `x` without testing the code? Actually, this is the kind of thing pylint should be catching.

Comment: @julio.alegria Why not the best, what do you see being a flaw ? At each turn of the loop, there are two (re-)assignements of the identifier _x_ to an object. In ``for myvar in (t[1] for t in mylist)`` there are also two assignements. In ``for _, myvar in mylist`` too.

Comment: @Francis Avila Please, define "beautiful" and "clear" - I answered to THIS question in which there is _"I'm defining those two variables just to unwrap the second one, because I don't need the other."_ - No, I never automatically know anything. Knowing how work the underlying processes, I thought to my solution, and then I verified it. - Did you test if **pylint** effectively catches _"this kind of thing"_ ?

Comment: No need to get upset! The OP mentions beauty as a criterion for the solution. Binding to the same twice in the for loop doesn't seem very pythonic because it relies on knowing the order in which the tuple is unpacked.  Which seems less beautiful and clear (or rather less explicit) than just binding to a different name without using it. The "this kind of thing" I refer to is binding to the same variable name multiple times on the left side of a tuple assignment.

Comment: Actually I don't even know offhand if tuple unpacking from left to right is specified behavior or an implementation detail!

Comment: @Francis Avila I'm not upset, I'm just very surprised. Concerning your point, see (http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) By the way, what do you call _"specified behavior"_ and its difference with _"implementation"_ ?

Comment: OK, good, thanks for the link. I still think "explicit is better than implicit", so while this code works I would personally never use it and would like a tool like pylint to complain about it.

Comment: @Francis Avila I really don't understand where there is a problem. The interpreter assigns the first element of a tuple to the first identifier at the left-hand, and then assigns the second element of the tuple to the second identifier at the left-hand. The execution model is so that the second assignement consists in fact in a reassignement because the identifier in the second place is the same as the identifier in the first place. No mystery nor weird process.

Comment: This answer isn't a good model to follow.  Many readers would find it confusing.  It would not pass most code reviews.

Comment: downvoting this answer. This is ugly and evil, and won't get past code review where I work, as it will pose maintainability issues.

Comment: I repeat what I said in my first comment: _not the best thing to do, but at least answers my question._ So, from what I'm seeing, there is no way to make Python ignore the assignation, just ugly-unreadable stuff or idiomatic stuff.

Comment: @julio: It doesn't answer your question; like other answers, it is still "assing the first part".

Comment: @julio.alegria: WRONG, it is assigning to `x` TWICE.

Comment: @JohnMachin: sorry, I meant: just one variable. Uppercase wrong... that made me feel like you're yelling :(

Comment: @julio.alegria: While you may have meant "just one variable", that is not what your question asked for.