# Python while loop issues

Tags: python, file-io, while-loop

Infile is a genealogy:

```
holla   1755
ronaj   1781
asdflæj 1803
axle    1823
einar   1855
baelj   1881
æljlas  1903
jobbi   1923
gurri   1955
kolli   1981
Rounaj  2004
```

I want to print out every generation time from infile and in the end I want the average. Here I think my issue is that `line2` gets out of range when the infile ends:

```
def main():
    infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
    line = infile.readline()
    tmpstr = line.split('\t')
    age=[]
    while line !='':
        line2 = infile.readline()
        tmpstr2 = line2.split('\t')
        age.append(int(tmpstr2[1]) - int(tmpstr[1]))
        print age
        tmpstr = tmpstr2
    infile.close()
    print sum(age)*1./len(age)
main()
```

So I decided to read all information to a list but `tmpstr` doesn´t change value here:

```
def main():
    infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
    line = infile.readline()
    age=[]
    while line !='':
        tmpstr = line.split('\t')
        age.append(tmpstr[1])
        print age
    infile.close()
    print sum(age)*1./len(age)
main()
```

How come? What's wrong with these two scripts? Why am I writing `main()` two times?
Any ideas how these two can be solved?

Thanx all, this is how it ended up:

```
   def main():
        with open('infile.txt', 'r') as input:
            ages = []
            for line in input:
                data = line.split()
                age = int(data[1])
                ages.append(age)
            gentime = []
            for i in xrange(len(ages)-1):
                print ages[i+1] - ages[i]
                gentime.append(ages[i+1] - ages[i]) 
            print 'average gentime is', sum(gentime)*1./len(gentime)
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest this go on [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: @Martin: codereview.SE is not for broken code.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: okay, good point. I did not think of it like that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def main():
    with open('infile.txt', 'r') as input:
        ages, n = 0, 0
        for line in input:
            age = int(line.split()[1])
            ages += age
            n += 1
            print age
        print 'average:', float(ages) / n
```

Some comments:

- You don't need to use a list for accumulating the numbers, a couple of local variables are enough
- In this case it's a good idea to use `split()` without arguments, in this way you'll process the input correctly when the name is separated from the number in front of it by spaces *or* tabs
- It's also a good idea to use the `with` syntax for opening a file and making sure that it gets closed afterwards

With respect to the final part of your question, "Why am I writing main() two times?" that's because the first time you're *defining* the `main` function and the second time you're *calling* it.

Comment: Maybe you rather want `float(ages) / n`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the entire contents of the file using this statement:

```
for line in infile:
    # Perform the rest of your steps here
```

You wouldn't want to use a while loop, unless you had some sort of counter to switch index locations (i.e. you used `infile.readlines()` and wanted to use a while loop for that).

Answer (score 1):

In the second instance, your code only reads a single line from the file.

Something simpler, like:

```
age = []
with open('data.txt', 'rt') as f:
   for line in f:
      vals = line.split('\t')
      age.append(int(vals[1]))

print sum(age) / float(len(age))
```

generates

```
1878.54545455
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = open("infile.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    gens = [int(x.split('\t')[1]) for line in lines]
    avg = sum(gens)/len(gens)
```

The first line is the native entrance for python into a program.  It is equivalent to C's "int main()".

Next, its probably easiest to set up for list comprehensions if you read all lines from the file into the list.

The 4th line iterates through the file lines splitting them at the tab and only retrieving the 2nd item (at index 1) from the newly split list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with both of these scripts is that your `while` loop is infinite. The condition `line != ''` will never be false unless the first line is empty.

You could fix this, but it's better to use the Python idiom:

```
lastyear = None
ages = []
for line in infile:
    _name, year = line.split('\t')
    year = int(year)
    if lastyear:
        ages.append(year - lastyear)
    lastyear = year
print float(sum(ages))/len(ages)
```

Comment: why is underscore the first character in _name?

Comment: That's just a hint to the reader that `_name` is needed for tuple unpacking but will not be used. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378213/1002469).