# Rewrite of zip function won't work

Tags: python

I'm rewriting the zip function as a practice of my Python skills. The aim is to write it using list comprehension, although I am not 100% sure I am fully comfortable with it hence I'm doing this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def zip(l1, l2):
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])

z = zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2,3])
for i in z: print(i)
```

And here is the error I am getting, which I am unsure of how to fix!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-omitted", line 47, in <module>
    z = zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2,3])
  File "path-omitted", line 45, in zip
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
  File "path-omitted", line 45, in zip
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
  File "path-omitted", line 45, in zip
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
  File "path-omitted", line 45, in zip
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: When writing a recursive function you must *always* ask yourself "what is the terminating condition?" If not, you end up at this site.

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't ever name a function the same as a built in/standard lib function - that way lies confusion and unmaintainability if it in any way ever behaves slightly differently from the original. From a practical perspective, using different names will allow you to compare the output of your new implementation with the original :-)

Comment: @barny I do realise this, however for practice I named it the same for reference :) I do not intend on comparing it

Comment: @barny +1, I agree with you. That's why I called it `zippy` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `zip` function implementation is recursive. At some point `l1[1:]` or `l2[1:]` will become empty, and attempts to access the first element will fail with `IndexError`.

Check if both `l1` and `l2` are nonempty and return empty list if they are:

```
def zip(l1, l2):
    if not (l1 and l2):
        return []
    return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
```

Or you could catch `IndexError` and return `[]`:

```
def zip(l1, l2):
    try:
        return [(l1[0], l2[0])] + zip(l1[1:], l2[1:])
    except IndexError:
        return []
```

Comment: so for example in Standard ML, you can return [] which returns the recursive answer on a list, or an empty list if the case is true for the first call. Is it the same practically?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: I can't comment on Standard ML... I used `[]`, which is the empty list literal, as part of [*"a terminating scenario that does not use recursion to produce an answer"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, `seq[1:]` is legitimate even for the empty sequence-- you just get an empty subsequence back. The problem is when you try to dereference the zero element in the next recursive call.

So fix your code by ensuring you stop recursing when you run out of elements *in either of the two arguments.*

Also, be warned that Python does not support unlimited recursion; use your function with very long lists, and you'll trigger a recursion error. But that's (theoretically) not the fault of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursion, it consumes much more memory than this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6,7]

def zippy(a,b):
    try:
        return [(a[i],b[i]) for i, _ in enumerate(a)]
    except:
        pass

print zippy(a,b)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: For my purpose I prefer to use recursion, but I guess for efficiency you're method is the best so far! I will keep an eye on this. But can you explain to me what you mean by the '_' and the 'pass' keyword? Thanks

Comment: @madcrazydrumma regarding the underscore `_` read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745018/python-is-there-a-dont-care-symbol-for-tuple-assignments

Comment: @madcrazydrumma regarding `pass` keyword, it's just to pass instead of taking action on the Exception. It's usually a bad practice because the idea is to detect and catch the exception and show an appropriate message. But in this case you know it will fail sometime because lists may not have the same length, so it is not a bad practice in this case.

Comment: @madcrazydrumma my pleasure!