# How to ignore the rest of the parameters that return by the function?

Tags: python, tuples, return-value

```
def get():
   ...
   ...
   return x,y,z

a,b,c = get()
```

i don't need b, c is there a solution to ignore them (**something like don't care**)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - is there a "don't care" symbol for tuple assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745018/python-is-there-a-dont-care-symbol-for-tuple-assignments)

Comment: `a, *_ = get()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended way of doing this is to use the _ variable name, as indicated by Abdul Niyas P M, this will not store the values captured by the _.

```
x, _, z = 1, 2, 3 # if x and z are necessary
# or
x, *_ = 1, 2, 3   # if only x is necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed that if you just do something like `a = get()` Python will throw all 3 values into the variable 'a' as a tuple.

The best and simplest solution possible at the moment (in the current python version 3.8) is to simply create a second variable to throw stuff in and not ever use that variable.
For example:

```
a, b = get()
```

However some people like to use a variable named *_ to indicate that this value is trash and needs to be ignored (The variable name adds nothing special, its just a convention to indicate we wont use it [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726155/is-an-acceptable-way-to-ignore-arguments-in-python))

```
a, *_ = get()
```

Comment: I think it would need to be a, *b = get(), otherwise there will be an error thrown that the number of return values does not fit the number of given variables...

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, within the returned tuple of values, you are interested only in the `k` th value.

You could then do:

```
a = get()[k]
```

assuming of course, that we're counting `k` from `0` (and not from `1`)

Comment: Why would one assume k counts from 1?

Comment: @adirabargil "One" doesn't assume anything, not even "zero". :-)

Comment:  exactly! Your answer seems right to me The most.